# JclMapi mapi general failure

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I have the code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  aMail: TJclEMail;
begin
  aMail := TJclEMail.Create;
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    aMail.Recipients.Add('service@blabla.com');
    aMail.Subject := '[IMPORTANT] blablba';

    aMail.Body := 'text text text text';
    aMail.Send(True);
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    aMail.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This throws: MAPI Error: (2) "General MAPI failure"
Any idea?

ps:
OS Windows 7
Outlook 2010
Delphi 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my Jedi library wasnt up to date. I search into jedi repository and JclMapi has change in Tue Dec 27 (Mantis 5748: JclMapi incompatibilities with 64-bit.)
Download this changes, re-compile pkg and now works perfectly!

Thank you anyway!!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same as you, just wrapped inside a class and it is working.

I use to check if MAPI is OK at the first time I execute Send():

```
function TMAPIPrerequisites.IsClientAvailable: Boolean;
var
  SimpleMAPI: TJclSimpleMapi;
begin
  SimpleMAPI := TJclSimpleMapi.Create;
  try
    Result := SimpleMAPI.AnyClientInstalled;
  finally
    SimpleMAPI.Free;
  end;
end;

function TMAPIPrerequisites.IsMapiAvailable: Boolean;
var
  SimpleMAPI: TJclSimpleMapi;
begin
  SimpleMAPI := TJclSimpleMapi.Create;
  try
    Result := SimpleMAPI.SimpleMapiInstalled;
  finally
    SimpleMAPI.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I Create a wrapper, called TEmailWrapper and the send method use your function "IsMapiAvailable" before execute, function returns true but send continues throwing MAPI Error: (2) "General MAPI failure"

Answer (score 0):

The above code works fine IF email client is not already running.

After struggling with same problem i found that the MAPI client has to run in same user context as the MAPI server (e-mail client - Thunderbird in my case).

However, if calling from an app started with administrator privileges (for example an app running in the debugger) then the MAPI calls would fail with error code 2. If both caller and email client are running as admin then everything works (but who's crazy enough to run e-mail client as admin these days?).